# TLS Certificate for SMTP Server

Tags: ios, mail.app, encryption

I have an e-mail account that uses a TLS client certificate as an additional layer of security on both incoming and outgoing e-mails.

**NOTE**: This is different from simply encrypting the connection (server certificate). A client certificate is used to verify the user connecting to the server, basically you open an encrypted connection to the server, it asks for a client certificate, and you reply using one, if it's invalid you have to try again or close the connection.

This works perfectly fine on macOS, as when I go into advanced settings in Mail.app I can ensure the TLS certificate is set for both the IMAP and SMTP settings for the account under:

- **IMAP**: Mail -> Accounts -> name@example.org -> Advanced IMAP Settings
- **SMTP**: Mail -> Accounts -> name@example.org -> Edit SMTP Server List -> example.org -> Advanced

However, on iOS I see nowhere to set this, yet it seems like the certificate I installed is being used for the IMAP connection as expected and that's working fine, but it's not working for the SMTP side, meaning I can't send any e-mails (after a short delay I get a message asking me to check my settings).

So I guess I have two questions:

1. Can anyone confirm whether TLS client certificates are supported for outgoing (SMTP) connections?
2. If the first answer is yes, does anyone know what the requirements are for iOS to select a client certificate for use in SMTP, as it seems I'm not meeting them? Is there any way to tell the iOS version of Mail.app to use a specific certificate of my choice?